# How do you align wrapping list items with TailwindCSS?

Tags: list, tailwind-css

When a newline occurs, the text of a list didn't align at the same x-position as the beginning. How do I go about modifying the class name or are there any alternative that leave left margin?

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="m-50">
  <ul class="w-1/4 mx-auto bg-cyan-500 list-disc list-inside">
    <li>List number 1 always goes first</li>
    <li>List number 2 is second</li>
    <li>List number 3... is stackoverflowed</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Style libraries don't offer everything under the sun. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132341/custom-html-list-bullets-text-wrapping-aligning.

Comment: You'll need to modify your html slightly but this can be accomplished using tailwind. https://play.tailwindcss.com/MP6HtUzspw. Docs on line position https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-position

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
<ul class="list-disc list-outside ms-8">
<li>Test</li>
<ul>
```

Combining [List Style Position](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-position) and [Margin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#using-logical-properties).